# ColdFusion: Integer "0" doesn't convert to ASCII character

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, ascii, hex, blowfish

I have a string (comprised of a userID and a date/time stamp), which I then encrypt using ColdFusion's *Encrypt(inputString, myKey, "Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "Hex")*.

In order to interface with a 3d party I have to then perform the following:

1. Convert each character pair within the resultant string into a HEX value.
2. HEX values are then represented as integers.
3. Resultant integers are then output as ASCII characters.
4. All the ASCII characters combine to form a Bytestring.
5. Bytestring is then converted to Base64.
6. Base64 is URL encoded and finally sent off (phew!)

It all works seamlessly, APART FROM when the original cfEncrypted string contains a "00".

The HEX value 00 translates as the integer (via function InputBaseN) 0 which then refuses to translate correctly into an ASCII character!

The resultant Bytestring (and therefore url string) is messed up and the 3d party is unable to decipher it.

*It's worth mentioning that I do declare: <cfcontent type="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> at the top of the page.*

Is there any way to correctly output 00 as ASCII? Could I avoid having "00" within the original encrypted string? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide a small test case, including actual versus expected results? (Also, I am not sure why you need step 1 if your encrypt() is returning "hex" ..)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure ColdFusion (and the Java underneath) use a null-terminated string type.  This means that every string contains one and only one asc(0) char, which is the string terminator.  If you try to insert an asc(0) into a string, CF is erroring because you are trying to create a malformed string element.

I'm not sure what the end solution is.  I would play around with toBinary() and toString(), and talk to your 3rd party vendor about workarounds like sending the raw hex values or similar.

Comment: The only way I have found to create a true null character is URLDecode("%00) http://www.coldfusiondeveloper.com.au/go/note/2007/05/06/null-character/

Comment: .. Though I am not sure that is even the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. I ended up bypassing the problem (thanks to a pointer by Leigh) by skipping the whole manual-hex-decimal-base64 process.

By using Encrypt(inputString, myKey, "Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "Base64") straight from the offset, CF did the hard work for me (d'oh!).

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a very easy solution. The credit card company who is processing your request needs you to convert it to lower case letters of hex. The only characters processed are :,-,0-9 do a if else and convert them manually into a string.